# How can I read a 4-byte data that is stored in two different register address from modbus?

Tags: automation, communication, modbus, scada, meter

I am using an Energy Meter to read different parameters from a power plant (voltage, current, etc.). This Energy Meter is connected to a Weintex PLC in order to show this data on an HMI.

The thing is, I have items like "Total kWh", "Export kWh" or "Import KWh" that are taking 2 register addresses. For example, "Total kWh" is 4 byte long and covers registers 0x0000 and 0x0001.

I have no idea how to get this item using EasyBuilder Pro. The rest of the data that is only on one register works perfectly. Is there something I am missing with the EasyBuilder Pro tool?

Thank you so much for your time!

I have tried to get this data using every type of lenght and type of variable, but nothing has worked for me at the moment.

Comment: I don't think most people here (including me) are familiar with EasyBuilder Pro. Can you provide examples of how you've attempted to get the two registers and convert them to proper data? How are you currently getting normal 16-bit registers? Include that code as well please.

Comment: Have a look how it is implemented in [ModBus Library for Zabbix](https://github.com/v-zhuravlev/libzbxmodbus). Maybe it will be useful for you.

Comment: You tried creating an address tag and setting the data format to 32-bit (the address+1 is automatically combined with address) as shown in 16-4 of this [manual](https://dl.weintek.com/public/EBPro/UserManual/eng/EasyBuilderPro_V60802_UserManual_eng.pdf)?